# Intent filter and nullPointerException after launching activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, intentfilter

I am stuck and facing problem with intent-filter in android! 
In my app when user taps on `buy product` button user will be redirected to internet browser (chrome etc) and after payment, user should come back to app, but occurred `NullPinterException` in `onCreate` Activity where I used `TextView`,`ImageView`.

I don't know why this problem happend, Please help!

`ActivityPayment.java`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
        Utils.toast("onCreate");
        initUI();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        final ModelVoucher v = (ModelVoucher) extras.get("voucher");

            Picasso.with(G.currentActivity)
                    .load(G.URL + v.imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.img_holder)
                    .error(R.mipmap.img_holder)
                    .into(imgVoucher);
            txtTitle.setText(v.title);
            txtUnitPrice.setText(v.payPrice);
            txtPayableAmount.setText((v.payPrice * count));

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("1");
            list.add("2");
            list.add("3");
            SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(G.context, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
            spnCount.setAdapter(adapter);

            spnCount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String selected = spnCount.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    count = Integer.valueOf(selected.trim());
                    txtPayableAmount.setText(v.payPrice * count );
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            lyFinalizeBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    new RequestPayment(new IRequest() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompeletd(final ModelResult result) {
                            G.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (result.success) {
                                        Intent paymentPage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        paymentPage.setData(Uri.parse(G.URL + "/payment/pay/" + result.paymentHash));
                                        startActivity(paymentPage);
                                    } else {
                                        Utils.toast(result.message, true);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(int status) {

                        }
                    }).beforePay(v.id + "", count + "");


                }
            });

        }

        new RequestProfile(new IRequest() {
            @Override
            public void onCompeletd(final ModelResult result) {
                G.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (result.success) {
                            txtBalance.setText(result.user.balance);
                        } else {
                            Utils.toast(result.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(int status) {

            }
        }).getBaseInfo(); 

}
```

`Stack Trace`

```
> 12-04 12:56:26.507  12350-12350/ir.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.myapplication/ir.myapplication.ActivityPayment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ir.myapplication.ActivityPayment.onCreate(ActivityPayment.java:56)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

56 line that happend exception:

```
 Picasso.with(G.currentActivity)
                .load(G.URL + v.imageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.img_holder)
                .error(R.mipmap.img_holder)
                .into(imgVoucher);
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Question without any code ? Any stacktrace error ?

Comment: i know caused of nullPointerException and I know what is nullPointerException, my problem is that i dont know why this exception happend in this case

Comment: @PiyushGupta , added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please use below code ?

There is issue with **Null Pointer**.

How to **send object**:

```
ClassName details = new ClassName();
Intent i = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Editing", details);
startActivity(i);
```

How to **receive object**:

```
ClassName model = (ClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Editing");
```

Your **model class** must be **implemented** as **Serializable**.

```
Class ClassName implements Serializable {
}
```

I hope your issue would resolve.

Comment: not resolved! even I remove this line of code , but nullPointerException happend in next line,  `txtTitle.setText(v.title)` !!

Comment: @esmaeil, that means you are getting ModelVoucher v  = null, please serialize the ModelVoucher and pass as serializaExtra(model)

Comment: yeah it's null  thanks!:) , I have another question, I want user come back to  app but  when user done payment browser launch new activity!